# publishing iCalendar event in case of multiple calendars of the same user

Tags: icalendar, rfc2445

I work on a java app that creates and keeps track of various events and these events are to be published in the person's calendar. 
The application sends messsages in *iCalendar* format via email (iTIP/iMIP, not calDav), more precisely I intend to send a PUBLISH event. The thing is, we use Zimbra and every user may have multiple calendars created. But I think its not important whether we use Zimbra or Outlook, I believe it is common feature to allow users having multiple calendars.

**And the question is**: I wonder is it possible to specify (in the iCalendar/iTIP/iMIP msg) which calendar the event should be displayed in? Currently it's the 'primary' calendar.

I have walked through all relating rfc's (5545, 5546, 6047), but havent found the answer. Google hasn't helped neither.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

By analogy with calendar subscribing which differentiates the different calendar the user has subscribed by their filename/url, you should try giving the calendar a file name using the "Content-Disposition" property in your MIME message (see rfc2447 §2.6).

Comment: I've tried that, but unfortunatelly Content-Disposition does not seem to work as I need (at least not in Zimbra). But thanks for trying.